# How can I secure these inadequate/leaning deck supports?

Tags: deck

I am in the process of buying a house. The home inspector noted problems with the deck, most significantly "leaning posts."

[image]

- What would be required to get those 4x4 supports adequately secured to the deck surface?
- Does the fact that some of the precast foundations are tilted (that one in the back is just horrifying) mean that I'll need to have those reseated?
- Is any of this work feasible without disassembling the entire thing -- is it a better idea to look into a complete rebuild?

This isn't a tall deck (~3-4 feet off the ground at highest point), and the surface is approximately 15x15 feet.

Comment: That is...hilarious...if it weren't a safety issue. It looks like they were just plopped randomly on the ground with no care given to level or solid base. I think you need to consider a rebuild. You could maybe get by with temporary jacks and then reset each pier one-by-one but that could be tough crawling under a 3' deck.

Comment: It isn't quite funny enough to be worth leaving, but it is definitely hilarious ;)

Comment: may be due to frost heaving,

Comment: See if you can get some compensation for deck repairs on the purchase price.  It might be worth $1000

Comment: @ChrisCudmore It's going to be part of the negotiation going forward for sure -- what I've been unsure about was whether to adjust the price (to pay for a whole new deck) or request repairs (which seller would pay for before sale), and knowing whether repair was even _possible_ was my biggest question :)

Comment: I wouldnt go for repairs, they would br just as shoddy. Go for a discount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of different types of post to beam connectors.

Like this:
[image: post to beam connectors]

However, the real weird thing is that you don't really have beams. They are just supporting the joists with a bunch of random posts on concrete deck blocks...

If it were me I'd lose all of those and put in a couple (or more) beams under those joists and put some posts under those.

Not in that order, though. Leave the posts in, put in some proper beams and posts, and *then* lose the crappy ones you have there.

Below is an example of a similar height deck I did. There are two beams under the joists of this deck, and four piers (two for each beam). The beams are the ones with the white flashing tape on top. You can clearly see one in this image, and how I attached it to the joists.

[image: deck]

Comment: Build a proper beam then use proper pads and cribbing blocks like a manufactured home.

Answer (score 4):

Please if you ever see something like this DO NOT get under it; don't get on it, and don't stand too close to it.  The photo shows, literally, a "house of cards" with no lateral bracing in any direction - that could collapse at any time.

There's a lot of weight in that assembly, inadequately supported, with questionable stability. I've built and remodeled homes and done many framing projects meeting building safety code.  Another poster observed it would be so difficult to reconstruct from underneath it would be best to start over.

Comment: We ended up disassembling it. It was, indeed, a total disaster (and we found other hilariously bad construction techniques while taking it apart).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is years too late, but I would have installed temporary jacks, removed all the decking boards and driven in 2ft galvanised ground spikes (2 ft underground) adjacent to the existing bad foundations and built a subframe of beams under it.  Could have been done without removing the existing joists.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Late answers aren't a problem; we're looking to accumulate knowledge, and this is a great contribution.

Comment: This would have been worthwhile for a larger deck, and so it's a great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used a rock bar a tire and a tie down strap to pull the board somewhat straight then wedged in 2×4 cut and beat them in to straighten them

Comment: Is this what was done to fix the OP's actual deck from 6 years ago, or is this what you did to fix a similar situation on your deck? Your wording is a bit confusing.